# My AirPods do not keep their charge nor do they charge in general

Tags: battery, charging, airplay

I am having trouble charging my AirPods.

I only got them a month ago and they were working completely fine. I take very good care of them, keeping them in the box when not in use. I came to charge them the day before last, using a brand new charger cable and cube for about an hour. When I came back to use them I noticed that while unplugging them the light was still orange. Also, when I opened them next to my phone to see the amount of charge it says, "14%" and left and right ear "7%."

I also noticed the case was hot. Then the orange light on the case turned off and after plugging it in again over night the charge was at 7% for the left and 1% for the right ear 1%.

Now charging them on the computer for the same time frame and checking with the same outcome, but rising case charge but then dropping drastically after placing back in charger without a single use.

Can anyone suggest what I should try next?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, can you clarify the *"using a brand new charger cable and cube for about an hour"* point you made? Is this when the problem started? Were you also using the 'new' charger cable when connected to the computer? What happens when you try using the original cable etc?